# Good PPA for ffmpeg

Tags: ppa, video-editor, ffmpeg

Its annoying that the default ffmpeg in ubuntu's repositories is outdated and hobbled for legal reasons, however, there's a great page on the forums that walks you through building it from scratch: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095
(I also add in support for --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex when I build, which is nice, but not essential.)

Anyway, I'm getting set to setup a computer lab running ubuntu for a multimedia class I'm teaching, and I was wondering if there was PPA out there that did something similar to what is available when building from scratch.  The things I absolutely need from it are up-to-date libxvid, libx264, libfaac, and libmp3lame support plus the un-encumbered stuff (vorbis, theora, vpx).

Is there a PPA out there that provides something like this?

Answer (score 6):

For older releases we may be able to install the [libavcodec-extra-52](http://packages.medibuntu.org/maverick/libavcodec-extra-52.html) package from [Medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org/) that includes ffmpeg 0.6. Newer Ubuntu versions are supported from Medibuntu with the **libavcodec-extra-53**-library.

Note that recent Ubuntu versions have [libavcode-extra-53](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libavcodec-extra-53) [image: Install libavcodec-extra-53] together with [ffmpeg](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ffmpeg) [image: Install ffmpeg] or [avconv](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avconv) [image: Install avconv] installable from the repositories too.

Comment: Just to clarify: Medibuntu isn't actually official (although it is very widely used)

Comment: @fluteflute: ++1, that's exactly why I put it in quotes ;)

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

> FFmpeg Ubuntu packages for Precise, Oneiric, Natty, Maverick, and Lucid (amd64, i386) are available at [Jon Severinsson's FFmpeg PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg).

I don't think there can be any better PPA than this ;)

Comment: Your link is broken...

Answer (score 2):

You can go here: https://launchpad.net/~siretart/+ppa-packages to see several ppa maintainers. The latest appear around October of last year.

Answer (score 0):

Sam Rog maintains [a current build of ffmpeg in his PPA](https://launchpad.net/~samrog131/+archive/ppa).
(Widely quoted, as in [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/ffmpeg-2-0-ppa-available-for-ubuntu-13-04-13-10-12-10/) and [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-ffmpeg-2-0-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-linux-mint-15-14-13-and-elementary-os-0-2-luna-via-ppa/).)

Jon Severinsson's FFmpeg PPA is the most official one, but it is way behind, at version 0.10.

Alternatively to using a PPA, the pre-built binaries are available from [the download page](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).
 Consider  wget/tar/mv as a simple alternative to adding a ppa and installing.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
apt install -y ffmpeg
```