# Why is the video blinking?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, video

I recently installed ubuntu 12.04 on my system, and completely installed all the updates on my system. I am having issues with video playback.

I was using default media player to play my videos, but since the maximum volume is very low in the default media player, I switched to VLC to play my videos.

Now, whenever I play any of the videos using VLC, then the screen starts "blinking" after every 3-5 seconds, It is really very annoying.

Thinking that this is a issue with VLC, I installed SM Player and played videos on it but the same problem occurs.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem, or increase volume in the default media player ?

In case, it matters, I have a Samsung Laptop, with AMD processor

Answer (score 0):

It's may be problem with your video card. Try booting in [Recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

Comment: Then, why doesn't this happen, when I use Default media player in ubuntu

Comment: Is your visual effect on? Check it  by **Preference> Appearence> Visual Effect**. If it is on, then select **NONE**.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to audio and video encoders/decoders. For audio encoders/decoders: try to update your system with

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You can also try another video player

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:exmplayer-dev/exmplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install exmplayer
```

Check out for more info http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/exmplayer-updated-to-version-380.html

For video encoders/decoders look for latest ppas [Good PPA for ffmpeg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21400/good-ppa-for-ffmpeg)